# python3: Split time series by diurnal periods

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataset:

```
01/05/2020,00,26.3,27.5,26.3,80,81,73,22.5,22.7,22.0,993.7,993.7,993.0,0.0,178,1.2,-3.53,0.0
01/05/2020,01,26.1,26.8,26.1,79,80,75,22.2,22.4,21.9,994.4,994.4,993.7,1.1,22,2.0,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,02,25.4,26.1,25.4,80,81,79,21.6,22.3,21.6,994.7,994.7,994.4,0.1,335,2.3,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,03,23.3,25.4,23.3,90,90,80,21.6,21.8,21.5,994.7,994.8,994.6,0.9,263,1.5,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,04,22.9,24.2,22.9,89,90,86,21.0,22.1,21.0,994.2,994.7,994.2,0.3,268,2.0,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,05,22.8,23.1,22.8,90,91,89,21.0,21.4,20.9,993.6,994.2,993.6,0.7,264,1.5,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,06,22.2,22.8,22.2,92,92,90,20.9,21.2,20.8,993.6,993.6,993.4,0.8,272,1.6,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,07,22.6,22.6,22.0,91,93,91,21.0,21.2,20.7,993.4,993.6,993.4,0.4,284,2.3,-3.49,0.0
01/05/2020,08,21.6,22.6,21.5,92,92,90,20.2,20.9,20.1,993.8,993.8,993.4,0.4,197,2.1,-3.54,0.0
01/05/2020,09,22.0,22.1,21.5,92,93,92,20.7,20.8,20.2,994.3,994.3,993.7,0.0,125,2.1,-3.53,0.0
01/05/2020,10,22.7,22.7,21.9,91,92,91,21.2,21.2,20.5,995.0,995.0,994.3,0.0,354,0.0,70.99,0.0
01/05/2020,11,25.0,25.0,22.7,83,91,82,21.8,22.1,21.1,995.5,995.5,995.0,0.8,262,1.5,744.8,0.0
01/05/2020,12,27.9,28.1,24.9,72,83,70,22.3,22.8,21.6,996.1,996.1,995.5,0.7,228,1.9,1392.,0.0
01/05/2020,13,30.4,30.4,27.7,58,72,55,21.1,22.6,20.4,995.9,996.2,995.9,1.6,134,3.7,1910.,0.0
01/05/2020,14,31.7,32.3,30.1,50,58,48,20.2,21.3,19.7,995.8,996.1,995.8,3.0,114,5.4,2577.,0.0
01/05/2020,15,32.9,33.2,31.8,44,50,43,19.1,20.5,18.6,994.9,995.8,994.9,0.0,128,5.6,2853.,0.0
01/05/2020,16,33.2,34.4,32.0,46,48,41,20.0,20.0,18.2,994.0,994.9,994.0,0.0,125,4.3,2700.,0.0
01/05/2020,17,33.1,34.5,32.7,44,46,39,19.2,19.9,18.5,993.4,994.1,993.4,0.0,170,1.6,2806.,0.0
01/05/2020,18,33.6,34.2,32.6,41,47,40,18.5,20.0,18.3,992.6,993.4,992.6,0.0,149,0.0,2319.,0.0
01/05/2020,19,33.5,34.7,32.1,43,49,39,19.2,20.4,18.3,992.3,992.6,992.3,0.3,168,4.1,1907.,0.0
01/05/2020,20,32.1,33.9,32.1,49,51,41,20.2,20.7,18.5,992.4,992.4,992.3,0.1,192,3.7,1203.,0.0
01/05/2020,21,29.9,32.2,29.9,62,62,49,21.8,21.9,20.2,992.3,992.4,992.2,0.0,188,2.9,408.0,0.0
01/05/2020,22,28.5,29.9,28.4,67,67,62,21.8,22.0,21.7,992.5,992.5,992.3,0.4,181,2.3,6.817,0.0
01/05/2020,23,27.8,28.5,27.8,71,71,66,22.1,22.1,21.5,993.1,993.1,992.5,0.0,225,1.6,-3.39,0.0
02/05/2020,00,27.4,28.2,27.3,75,75,68,22.5,22.5,21.7,993.7,993.7,993.1,0.5,139,1.5,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,01,27.3,27.7,27.3,72,75,72,21.9,22.6,21.9,994.3,994.3,993.7,0.0,126,1.1,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,02,25.4,27.3,25.2,85,85,72,22.6,22.8,21.9,994.4,994.5,994.3,0.1,256,2.6,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,03,25.5,25.6,25.3,84,85,82,22.5,22.7,22.1,994.3,994.4,994.2,0.0,329,0.7,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,04,24.5,25.5,24.5,86,86,82,22.0,22.5,21.9,993.9,994.3,993.9,0.0,290,1.2,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,05,24.0,24.5,23.5,87,88,86,21.6,22.1,21.3,993.6,993.9,993.6,0.7,285,1.3,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,06,23.7,24.1,23.7,87,87,85,21.3,21.6,21.3,993.1,993.6,993.1,0.1,305,1.1,-3.51,0.0
02/05/2020,07,22.7,24.1,22.5,91,91,86,21.0,21.7,20.7,993.1,993.3,993.1,0.6,220,1.1,-3.54,0.0
02/05/2020,08,22.9,22.9,22.6,92,92,91,21.5,21.5,21.0,993.2,993.2,987.6,0.0,239,1.5,-3.53,0.0
02/05/2020,09,22.9,23.0,22.8,93,93,92,21.7,21.7,21.4,993.6,993.6,993.2,0.0,289,0.4,-3.53,0.0
02/05/2020,10,23.5,23.5,22.8,92,93,92,22.1,22.1,21.6,994.3,994.3,993.6,0.0,256,0.0,91.75,0.0
02/05/2020,11,26.1,26.2,23.5,80,92,80,22.4,23.1,22.2,995.0,995.0,994.3,1.1,141,1.9,789.0,0.0
02/05/2020,12,28.7,28.7,26.1,69,80,68,22.4,22.7,22.1,995.5,995.5,995.0,0.0,116,2.2,1468.,0.0
02/05/2020,13,31.4,31.4,28.6,56,69,56,21.6,22.9,21.0,995.5,995.7,995.4,0.0,65,0.0,1762.,0.0
02/05/2020,14,32.1,32.4,30.6,48,58,47,19.8,22.0,19.3,995.0,995.6,990.6,0.0,105,0.0,2657.,0.0
02/05/2020,15,34.0,34.2,31.7,43,48,42,19.6,20.1,18.6,993.9,995.0,993.9,3.0,71,6.0,2846.,0.0
02/05/2020,16,34.7,34.7,32.3,38,48,38,18.4,20.3,18.3,992.7,993.9,992.7,1.4,63,6.3,2959.,0.0
02/05/2020,17,34.0,34.7,32.7,42,46,38,19.2,20.0,18.4,991.7,992.7,991.7,2.2,103,4.8,2493.,0.0
02/05/2020,18,34.3,34.7,33.6,41,42,38,19.1,19.4,18.0,991.2,991.7,991.2,2.0,141,4.8,2593.,0.0
02/05/2020,19,33.5,34.5,32.5,42,47,39,18.7,20.0,18.4,990.7,991.4,989.9,1.8,132,4.2,1317.,0.0
02/05/2020,20,32.5,34.2,32.5,47,48,40,19.7,20.3,18.7,990.5,990.7,989.8,1.3,191,4.2,1250.,0.0
02/05/2020,21,30.5,32.5,30.5,59,59,47,21.5,21.6,20.0,979.8,990.5,979.5,0.1,157,2.9,345.5,0.0
02/05/2020,22,28.6,30.5,28.6,67,67,59,21.9,21.9,21.5,978.9,980.1,978.7,0.6,166,2.2,1.122,0.0
02/05/2020,23,27.2,28.7,27.2,74,74,66,22.1,22.2,21.6,978.9,979.3,978.6,0.0,246,1.7,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,00,26.5,27.2,26.0,77,80,74,22.2,22.5,22.0,979.0,979.1,978.7,0.0,179,1.4,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,01,26.0,26.6,26.0,80,80,77,22.4,22.5,22.1,979.1,992.4,978.7,0.0,276,0.6,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,02,26.0,26.5,26.0,79,81,75,22.1,22.5,21.7,978.8,979.1,978.5,0.0,290,0.6,-3.53,0.0
03/05/2020,03,25.3,26.0,25.3,83,83,79,22.2,22.4,21.8,978.6,989.4,978.5,0.5,303,1.0,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,04,25.3,25.6,24.6,81,85,81,21.9,22.5,21.7,978.1,992.7,977.9,0.7,288,1.5,-3.00,0.0
03/05/2020,05,23.7,25.3,23.7,88,88,81,21.5,21.9,21.5,977.6,991.8,977.3,1.2,256,1.8,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,06,23.3,23.7,23.3,91,91,88,21.7,21.7,21.5,976.9,977.6,976.7,0.4,245,1.8,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,07,23.0,23.6,23.0,91,91,89,21.4,21.9,21.3,976.7,977.0,976.4,0.9,257,1.9,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,08,23.4,23.4,22.9,90,92,90,21.7,21.7,21.3,976.8,976.9,976.5,0.4,294,1.6,-3.52,0.0
03/05/2020,09,23.0,23.5,23.0,88,90,87,21.0,21.6,20.9,992.1,992.1,976.7,0.8,263,1.6,-3.54,0.0
03/05/2020,10,23.2,23.2,22.5,91,92,88,21.6,21.6,20.8,993.0,993.0,992.2,0.1,226,1.5,29.03,0.0
03/05/2020,11,26.0,26.1,23.2,77,91,76,21.6,22.1,21.5,993.8,993.8,982.1,0.0,120,0.9,458.1,0.0
03/05/2020,12,26.6,27.0,25.5,76,80,76,22.1,22.5,21.4,982.7,994.3,982.6,0.3,121,2.3,765.3,0.0
03/05/2020,13,28.5,28.7,26.6,66,77,65,21.5,23.1,21.2,982.5,994.2,982.4,1.4,130,3.2,1219.,0.0
03/05/2020,14,31.1,31.1,28.5,55,66,53,21.0,21.8,19.9,982.3,982.7,982.1,1.2,129,3.7,1743.,0.0
03/05/2020,15,31.6,31.8,30.7,50,55,49,19.8,20.8,19.2,992.9,993.5,982.2,1.1,119,5.1,1958.,0.0
03/05/2020,16,32.7,32.8,31.1,46,52,46,19.6,20.7,19.2,991.9,992.9,991.9,0.8,122,4.4,1953.,0.0
03/05/2020,17,32.3,33.3,32.0,44,49,42,18.6,20.2,18.2,990.7,991.9,979.0,2.6,133,5.9,2463.,0.0
03/05/2020,18,33.1,33.3,31.9,44,50,44,19.3,20.8,18.9,989.9,990.7,989.9,1.1,170,5.4,2033.,0.0
03/05/2020,19,32.4,33.2,32.2,47,47,44,19.7,20.0,18.7,989.5,989.9,989.5,2.4,152,5.2,1581.,0.0
03/05/2020,20,31.2,32.5,31.2,53,53,46,20.6,20.7,19.4,989.5,989.7,989.5,1.7,159,4.6,968.6,0.0
03/05/2020,21,29.7,32.0,29.7,62,62,51,21.8,21.8,20.5,989.7,989.7,989.4,0.8,154,4.0,414.2,0.0
03/05/2020,22,28.3,29.7,28.3,69,69,62,22.1,22.1,21.7,989.9,989.9,989.7,0.3,174,2.0,6.459,0.0
03/05/2020,23,26.9,28.5,26.9,75,75,67,22.1,22.5,21.7,990.5,990.5,989.8,0.2,183,1.0,-3.54,0.0
```

The second column is time (hour). I want to separate the dataset by morning (06-11), afternoon (12-17), evening (18-23) and night (00-05). How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```
bins = [-1,5,11,17,24]
labels = ['morning', 'afternoon', 'evening', 'night']

df['day_part'] = pd.cut(df['hour'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

I added column names, including *Hour* for the second column.

Then I used *read_csv* which reads the source text, "dropping" leading
zeroes, so that *Hour* column is just *int*.

To split rows (add a column marking the diurnal period), use:

```
df['period'] = pd.cut(df.Hour, bins=[0, 6, 12, 18, 24], right=False,
    labels=['night', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'evening'])
```

Then you can e.g. use *groupby* to process your groups.

Because I used *right=False* parameter, the bins are closed on the **left**
side, thus bin limits are more natural (no need for *-1* as an hour).

And bin limits (except for the last) are just **starting hours** of
each period - quite natural notation.