# Group time Data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

[I have time given in this format and I want to Group them in 6 categories like Early morning, Afternoon, Evening, etc. How can change the time format into categories? Is there any inbuilt library in Python that can help me do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvMMx.png)

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920265/python3-split-time-series-by-diurnal-periods/61920576#61920576) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671385/format-problem-categorizing-time-in-pandas/64671685#64671685).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it somewhat like that I guess.

```
import pandas as pd

# obviously you need to import the values from an external file.
time_list = ["10:00:00", "13:30:00", "09:30:00", "10:22:00", "01:00:00"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":time_list})

# once imported make sure to let pandas know which column contains date time.
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.groupby([df['time'].dt.hour])

# access the date time object 
df['hour'] = df['time'].dt.hour
df['hour'].replace({
    1:"night",
    9:"late morning",
    10:"late morning",
    13:"noon",

}, inplace=True)
```

This returns the Python file containing all the categories in the "hour" column. The categories have to be defined as a dict-type argument of the replace function.